# Why does it say this trigger contains sql syntax errors?

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, syntax-error

i have written a trigger in mysqlworkbench that should update the product stock after a new line had been added to the order table(my code is in dutch so thats why im explaining this) But it doesn't work, when i try to apply it mysqlworkbench says its sql code contains errors.

Here's the trigger:

```
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `winkel`.`bestelregel_AFTER_INSERT` AFTER INSERT ON `bestelregel` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    if Product.productnr = NEW.productnr
     then
        Update Product
        Set Hoeveelheid = (Hoeveelheid - NEW.aantal)
        Where productnr = NEW.productnr;

    end if;
END
```

Comment: Please add the full error to your post. It contains useful things like the line number.

Comment: Do you redefine the delimiter before defining the trigger?

Comment: It turned out Gordon was right, i tried this but it kept talking about an sql error, however after i just continued it worked, also mysql workbench automatically changes the delimiter to $$, thanks for all the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is `Product` in the `if` statement?  That is, no doubt, generating a syntax error, because it is unrecognized.

I think you intend for the body to be simply:

```
    Update Product p.
        Set Hoeveelheid = (Hoeveelheid - NEW.aantal)
        Where p.productnr = NEW.productnr;
```

The `if` irrelevant.

I would expect the full version to look something like:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `winkel`.`bestelregel_AFTER_INSERT`
    AFTER INSERT ON `bestelregel` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE Product p
        SET Hoeveelheid = (Hoeveelheid - NEW.aantal)
        WHERE p.productnr = NEW.productnr;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have delimiter trouble.  You need

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE ..... TRIGGER ...
BEGIN
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```